# Regarding Data functions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**There's no start date for some of the rows in the start date**

I have the below table, How to get the average of the difference between the start date and end date grouped by location in SQL

[image: Table: Loc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would use aggregation:

```
select avg(datediff(end_date, start_date))
from t
group by Location
```

This ignores rows where either or both values are `NULL`.